# How to import props in React Js using components ( react Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, import, react-hooks, react-props

I had this problem while importing props in a component in ReactJs Although there is a way to import states as Hooks while dealing with functions but in the case of Components **this.props.state** or **props.state** doesn't work

Comment: Class Component properties: `this.props`, state: `this.state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this** is a word reserved for class components. Which means you cant use it in hooks because you aren't defining a class but a functional component. if you are surprised because you never heard about functional component i can recommend you to read [this](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/)

In a functional component you use props and state like so:

```
const Component = ({id, name, ...get props here}) => {

 //here i define a state and a function to set it 
 const [state1, setState1] = useState('');


 // I can use the setter of my "state" to modify my state1 value
 setState1('Hello');

 return(
    <div>{state1} : {id}</div> // will display Hello: 265 if id in props is 265
  );
}
```